# Does liquibase support data migration from one database to another

Tags: database, migration, liquibase, data-migration, liquibase-hibernate

I have a scenario where we are migrating from ***Oracle DB to Postgres Sql***, I know I can generate a change-log from Oracle schema using liquibase maven plugin and can use the same to create my schema in Postgres. What i want to know is if its possible to copy the data from oracle to postgresql too using liquibase. If so, how to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can copy the data from one database to another using Liquibase changeSet directly.

But you can use `generateChangeLog` with `--diffTypes=data` attribute. It'll include data in the generated changeSets.

Check out the [generateChangeLog docs](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html)

> **–diffTypes** - List of diff types to include in changelog expressed as a
>   comma separated list from: tables, views, columns, indexes,
>   foreignkeys, primarykeys, uniqueconstraints, **data**.

And also check out this [example](https://gist.github.com/goyalmohit/e57025367d1494ce21dec19c9f3f967d)

```
liquibase   
        --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  
        --classpath="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server\\sqljdbc_6.0\\enu\\jre8"  
        --url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2017;integratedSecurity=false;"
        --changeLogFile="D:\Source\generateChangeLog--PersonSchema.xml"
        --username=liquibase
        --password=liquibase@123
        --logLevel=info
        --defaultSchemaName=dbo
        --diffTypes=data
        generateChangeLog
```

Comment: Thank you @htshame. I tried your solution and it seems to be working. But i use maven and liquibase is inside our app so i run this command to generate the changelog with data.
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data

Comment: Great, you're welcome! By Stackoverflow rules if the answer answers your question, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using liquibase. If you have the setup changelog, you can do it as hinted by @htshame. Note that you will need to amend the data a bit. I also recommend to use a dedicated data-output-directory (otherwise you will get a huge XML):

1. Set `liquibase.command.url` to the source server (or use the command line option)
2. `liquibase generateChangeLog --diffTypes data --data-output-directory=data --changeLogFile data.xml` will generate a data dump
3. Amend the data dump such that tables that act a Constraints for others are at the top of the data dump (and as such injected first).
4. Set `liquibase.command.url` to the target server
5. `liquibase drop-all` to (optionally clean the target DB)
6. `liquibase update --changelog-file setup.xml` will create all the tables, indices, constraints, etc.
7. `liquibase update --changelog-file data.xml` will then inject all the data

In case you are lacking the setup.xml changelog, you can do a full dump from the existing database:

1. Set `liquibase.command.url` to the source server (or use the command line option)
2. `liquibase generate-changelog --diff-types catalogs,tables,functions,views,columns,indexes,foreignkeys,primarykeys,uniqueconstraints,data,storedprocedures,triggers,sequences,databasepackage,databasepackagebody --changelog-file all.xml --data-output-directory=data` will generate a full dump
3. Possibly you need to amend data types of some fields in the XML (in case they don't exist in the target DB)
4. Set `liquibase.command.url` to the target server
5. `liquibase drop-all` to (optionally clean the target DB)
6. `liquibase update --changelog-file all.xml` will then rebuild the database on the target server

Note that in the second case, since you are using the data types of the source database, you may not have a 100% percent compliant setup. E.g. Camunda provides a setup.xml changelog and I strongly recommend to use it as it allows to integrate upcoming schema updates without difficulties.